# sort multidimensional array after loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, joomla

i want to sort my array by points of users. Like high to low . After complete loop i have get below value.

```
 Array(  [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [points_of_usrs] => 182
            [avatar] => 8f7036bce1f02648eea38b71ded64aea_medium.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
            [points_of_usrs] => 1095
            [avatar] => d3644f378eae3675e67b50b44a2fe4ab_medium.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [points_of_usrs] => 10
            [avatar] => 
        ))
```

And i want to sort this array like below

```
Array( [0] => Array
        (
             [name] => test
            [points_of_usrs] => 1095
            [avatar] => d3644f378eae3675e67b50b44a2fe4ab_medium.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
             [name] => test1
            [points_of_usrs] => 182
            [avatar] => 8f7036bce1f02648eea38b71ded64aea_medium.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [points_of_usrs] => 10
            [avatar] => 
        ))
```

Sort by High to low user points .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

(pcode)

```
function sortit( $a, $b )
{
    if( $a->points_of_usrs == $b->points_of_usrs ) return 0;
    else return ( $a->points_of_usrs - $b->points_of_usrs )
}

usort( $array, "sortit" );
```